# Where can I get street views of Hyderabad (India), similar to Google Maps?

Tags: india, maps, hyderabad

[Google Street View doesn't work in Hyderabad, India](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/google-street-view-proposal-rejected-by-govt/articleshow/63482412.cms) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180720034317/https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/google-street-view-proposal-rejected-by-govt/articleshow/63482412.cms)). Where can I get street views of Hyderabad, similar to Google Maps?

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- [Wonobo](https://www.wonobo.com/): the map doesn't load (tested on MSIE and Google Chrome)
- http://satellites.pro/Hyderabad.India and http://streetview.io/: photos are very sparse (i.e., one cannot go virtually around the street with it)

Answer (score 3):

Google Street View [does work in Hyderabad](http://www.gisresources.com/hyderabad-first-city-in-india-to-get-google-street-view/), however, only in certain regions.

[Example near the Central University](https://www.google.com/maps/@17.4566435,78.3395049,2a,75y,222.6h,90.17t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sThIHXorya3GJQqAnG2p6Nw!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DThIHXorya3GJQqAnG2p6Nw%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D343.5%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656).

Unfortunately Google tends to have the most extensive version of this technology.  OpenStreetMaps doesn't have the power or scope.  Panoramio used to be fantastic for looking at locations, but they've closed as well.

Unfortunately, you're probably restricted to looking at images on flickr, google maps / images, or other photo sharing services.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.mapillary.com offers images of a number of streets in Hyderabad, and while you can click through them in a similar fashion to Google maps, they are not 360 images. The majority of the images are sourced from dashcam footage.

[Current Hyderabad coverage](https://www.mapillary.com/app/?lat=17.417662114676006&lng=78.43973006872397&z=10.389870554276085&focus=map&pKey=ZQSBCMySLEbA_BHaG4P_HA):

[image]

[Screenshots of the interface with street view](https://www.mapillary.com/app/?lat=17.411675966252467&lng=78.43538320301775&z=17&focus=map&pKey=mxbzLQbOblr-KpsAMdaS3A) (focused on [Banjara Hills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banjara_Hills)):

[image]